# To create sub folders and adding files into it during Wix Installtion

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wix, windows-installer, package

I am doing a Wix Installation for my C# application, EVERYTHING SEEMS TO BE WORKING. However the following code is unable to create sub folders and not putting files into it. I will appreciate if you guys can review it and let me know what wrong I have done.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Product Id="*" Name="MyApp" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="MyApp" UpgradeCode="a84565c2-d23a-456e-a69b-507890e7d08b">
      <Package Id="*" InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

      <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
      <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

      <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyApp" Level="1">
          <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      </Feature>

  <!--User Interface-->
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />

  </Product>

  <Fragment>
      <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
          <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyApp" />
          </Directory>
  </Directory>

  <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <Directory Id="LangPL" Name="pl-PL" />
    <Directory Id="LangDE" Name="de-DE" />
    <Directory Id="LangNL" Name="nl-NL" />
    <Directory Id="LangIT" Name="it-IT" />
    <Directory Id="LangZH" Name="zh-Hans" />
    <Directory Id="LangES" Name="es-ES" />
    <Directory Id="LangRU" Name="ru-RU" />
    <Directory Id="LangFR" Name="fr-FR" />
    <Directory Id="LangUS" Name="en-US" />
  </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>

<!-- Fragment to Add files to install folder-->
  <Fragment>
      <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
    <Component Guid="{0F129003-1A21-4F8F-93E6-E1B5D32EA2E7}">
      <File Source="$(var.App.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Guid="{8E58912F-C519-4163-9DD8-1AB9D355A046}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\APP.exe.config" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>

    <!-- Database Files -->
    <Component Guid="{37ABA3DA-86D9-4523-BDB7-0AD5C3708762}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\DB.mdf" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Guid="{1194A878-D4B8-4B22-8F14-9D9EF93747D3}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\DB_log.ldf" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>

    <!-- DLL Files -->
    <Component Guid="{87FCEE21-E1C4-4A2C-AA62-B6C668AB0E52}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\AxInterop.AcroPDFLib.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Guid="{BFF2CCF9-3503-47AB-AB77-E78F273B2FC6}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Guid="{6C0D941F-A005-4E10-BAA6-391E70295EB2}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\Interop.AcroPDFLib.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Guid="{9B0BB779-74F3-456B-B616-BBF4BAE139E3}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\Interop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Guid="{09071A2C-1DB6-4AE5-9D9E-17DB57616D4B}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Guid="{75321BD4-C241-499F-90A6-B6363357F20C}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Guid="{46A6DBEC-D969-40F4-AAF3-AF212FE5281E}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Guid="{815B4D31-A7B8-4CD7-8470-99DFADF7AEE3}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Guid="{33354D4A-5CB6-49CB-8C05-18D0F3191538}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\Microsoft.SqlServer.SqlEnum.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Guid="{9D8D4126-A718-48D9-BA34-EAD91F30CE88}">
      <File Source="..\App\bin\Debug\Utilities.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
      </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>

<!-- Fragment for Language -->
<Fragment>

  <!-- Language Files -->
  <DirectoryRef Id="LangDE">
    <Component Id="cmp86C295D7F66EC9578F96F4623F089C67" Guid="{1C8790A6-41C2-4E16-8E31-10EDECE86247}">
      <File Id="fil3C1CE3C61A61928116642D76E1CB2FD1" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\App\bin\Debug\de-DE\App.resources.dll" />
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <DirectoryRef Id="LangPL">
    <Component Id="cmp8F8D4A93706A9F8808F5E2985188A413" Guid="{17C8306C-5974-405B-952F-DC45B0818E39}">
      <File Id="fil55B857264E5ABC88F6EA12CEA4B93C2A" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\App\bin\Debug\pl-PL\App.resources.dll" />
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <DirectoryRef Id="LangIT">
    <Component Id="cmpA89C227C566FDB4BCDF630318E40C7E5" Guid="{C09B8F97-ADD5-4FB8-8670-8BA1E34F6709}">
      <File Id="filA0C4161E00B664DB9961F7F1D1FC40AD" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\App\bin\Debug\it-IT\App.resources.dll" />
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <DirectoryRef Id="LangFR">
    <Component Id="cmpC6BCCBC4286751A9F3AA247597AD0861" Guid="{F74428CD-F7ED-4C36-8AE4-1BC72F43FCBA}">
      <File Id="fil1784EB69DBD3581198FFE97FB812B1E0" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\App\bin\Debug\fr-FR\App.resources.dll" />
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <DirectoryRef Id="LangUS">
    <Component Id="cmpCC8D717E06A1A3AC08A128C5A16928A2" Guid="{EC66B5A5-42F4-45AB-A782-9C4420855A25}">
      <File Id="filBF78840BD50DBF938D4331D2BE1EC95C" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\App\bin\Debug\en-US\App.resources.dll" />
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <DirectoryRef Id="LangES">
    <Component Id="cmpDDA77EFB7EFD0EAC732A90C4F40031CF" Guid="{2AFDCEEE-5F75-47CC-BE81-4473C523C583}">
      <File Id="fil702C9D4400C38C1E053F89C06FB02125" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\App\bin\Debug\es-ES\App.resources.dll" />
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <DirectoryRef Id="LangNL">
    <Component Id="cmpE263B74764498E93EE67602DF6EC34A3" Guid="{EBE1DC48-709A-4B27-ABFD-C2EAF1F8F045}">
      <File Id="fil25E319C7D7844EE691033BE7B5076021" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\App\bin\Debug\nl-NL\App.resources.dll" />
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <DirectoryRef Id="LangRU">
    <Component Id="cmpEA3A3E0AC21B81AC658C77C2DD655AB6" Guid="{E10BA360-E9ED-48D2-9A32-17E436764BA1}">
      <File Id="fil6C4DA2534BE3D68B4E4FB677FAC1660C" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\App\bin\Debug\ru-RU\App.resources.dll" />
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
  <DirectoryRef Id="LangZH">
    <Component Id="cmpF2AD194BB8C30284155E9D01AE39BF26" Guid="{7C236F8F-B790-4C8F-8573-3A86D083BC7B}">
      <File Id="fil0A5479D9006A1049B58101823121F91A" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\App\bin\Debug\zh-Hans\App.resources.dll" />
    </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Your `Land*` components are not included into any feature, that's why those doesn't get installed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not adding the components containing your Directories to any feature.

You need to create a ComponentGroup containing every one of the Component ID's of your Directories and then a ComponentGroupRef to that in your Feature.

However I suggest to create a new sub feature "Language packs" and another sub feature of it for each language and then your users will have the option to install or not specific language packages.

Something like this:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="MyApp" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
      <Feature Id="LanguagePacks" Title="Language Packs" Level="1">
          <Feature Id="FrenchPack" Title="French" Level="1">
              <ComponentRef Id="FrenchComponentId" />
          </Feature>
          <Feature Id="ItalianPack" Title="Italian" Level="1">
              <ComponentRef Id="ItalianComponentId" />
          </Feature>

      </Feature>
  </Feature>
```